# Convert UDT subtype to supertype

Tags: oracle, oop, type-conversion, geospatial, user-defined-types

I use a user-defined type (UDT) in Oracle 18c called ST_GEOMETRY:

- [The ST_Geometry storage type](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm)
- [ST_Geometry in Oracle](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/stgeometry-oracle.htm)
- [SQL functions used with ST_Geometry](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/a-quick-tour-of-sql-functions-used-with-st-geometry.htm)
- ST_GEOMETRY (a proprietary datatype) is not to be confused with Oracle's MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY.

I have a query that produces a ST_GEOMETRY supertype:

```
select
    sde.st_geometry('LINESTRING(1 2,3 4,5 6)', 26917) as geom
from
    dual
    
[SDE.ST_GEOMETRY]
```

I want to select a specific vertex of that geometry -- the ***startpoint*** of that ST_GEOMETRY line:

```
select
    sde.st_startpoint(sde.st_geometry('LINESTRING(1 2,3 4,5 6)', 26917)) as startpoint
from
    dual
    
[SDE.ST_POINT]
```

Notice that the output is the ST_POINT subtype, not the ST_GEOMETRY supertype.

The startpoint query runs without errors in an SQL client. However, I want to use the query in GIS software that has a limitation where it can't use the ST_POINT subtype. It can only use the ST_GEOMETRY supertype.

The software vendor blames Oracle for this issue: [Bug: Unable to define a query layer in ArcGIS where the data source uses an st_geometry subtype in Oracle](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011333). The software vendor suggests the following workaround (although they don't say [***how*** to do it](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-ideas/improve-the-docs-how-to-quot-convert-st-point/idi-p/1184196)):

> Convert the geometry attribute field from the subtype (for example,
> st_point) to the supertype st_geometry.

So, I want to use Oracle's [TREAT() function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TREAT.html) to convert from the ST_POINT subtype to the ST_GEOMETRY supertype:

```
select
    treat(sde.st_startpoint(sde.st_geometry('LINESTRING(1 2,3 4,5 6)', 26917)) as sde.st_geometry) startpoint_geom
from
    dual

[SDE.ST_POINT]
```

That query runs without errors in an SQL client. But it doesn't seem to be converting to the ST_GEOMETRY supertype correctly. The output is still the ST_POINT subtype, which isn't what I want. (It’s still causing problems in the GIS software.)

---

How can I use the TREAT() function to convert a UDT subtype to the supertype?

I'm aware that there are other workarounds like converting from `subtype` to `text` to `supertype`. But that is ugly and slow. I would prefer to use the TREAT() function to do the conversion, since I think that would be cleaner/faster.

---

Related: [Convert MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING subtype value to MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY supertype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72682803/convert-mdsys-st-linestring-subtype-value-to-mdsys-st-geometry-supertype)

Comment: Please include a [MRE] with: the DDL statements that replicate the issue as I am having trouble replicating your issue casting UDTs to a supertype [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6dd788ff795b4e0aa051f850d64cfa12).

Comment: The bug says "or the st_geometry attribute values were created using a subtype constructor" which seems to be the case with the TREAT'd value, maybe? It also says "convert any geometry values which were created with a subtype to st_geometry, by using the st_geometry constructor" - so is there a `new sde.st_geometry(...)` constructor that takes your point as an argument (without converting to/from text)?

Comment: @MTO Like you, I will need to learn how to create types/objects from scratch. It's not something that I've needed to do until now. The GIS software comes with that stuff out-of-the-box. Will let you know if I can get something working.

Comment: @AlexPoole Regarding *"The bug says "or the st_geometry attribute values were created using a subtype constructor" which seems to be the case with the TREAT'd value, maybe?"* To be honest, I'm not really knowledgeable enough to say anything useful about that yet. I'll need to think it over.

Comment: @AlexPoole Regarding *"is there a new `sde.st_geometry(...)` constructor that takes your point as an argument (without converting to/from text)?"* As far as I can tell, the only st_geometry constructor is `st_geometry()`, which can only accept text as the argument. Example: This query doesn't work, because the argument isn't text: `select sde.st_geometry(sde.st_startpoint(sde.st_geometry('LINESTRING(1 2,3 4,5 6)', 26917)), 26917) as startpoint_supertype from dual`. Error: `ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ST_GEOMETRY'`. I think the "wrong type" is the issue.

Comment: St_Geometry constructor: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-geometry.htm