# Treat Oracle subtype as supertype

Tags: oracle, inheritance, type-conversion, oracle18c, oracle-spatial

I have a query that uses Oracle's **MDSYS**.ST_GEOMETRY type ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/sql-multimedia-type-support.html#GUID-22FE0E11-C9F0-4E1A-B512-D494E588FFAA)):

```
select
    mdsys.st_point(1, 2, 26917)
from 
    dual

Output:
[MDSYS.ST_POINT]
```

The query outputs the ST_POINT **sub**type.

I want to convert the ST_POINT subtype to the ST_GEOMETRY **super**type:

```
select
    treat(
        mdsys.st_point(1, 2, 26917)
    as st_geometry)
    .st_geometrytype() --optional; helps when running the query in DB<>FIDDLE or Oracle Live SQL, since those DBs don't output spatial types correctly.   
from 
    dual

Output:
ST_POINT
```

I would have thought that I could use the TREAT() function to make the conversion.

> [TREAT()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TREAT.html)
>
> You can use the TREAT function to change the declared type of an
> expression.

But as you can see in the query above, even though I used the TREAT() function, the output is still the ST_POINT subtype, not the ST_GEOMETRY supertype.

And for what it's worth, the same thing happens with a [User-defined Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133976/use-treat-function-to-convert-udt-subtype-to-supertype).

---

How can I convert an Oracle subtype to its supertype?

Related: [2.3 Inheritance in SQL Object Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adobj/inheritance-in-sql-object-types.html#GUID-D6D92FB6-7BC4-4EE6-A9EC-BC69C5BA5A56)

Comment: A [MRE] that might be a useful example is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=588d1685dc20a504d24b1d75b1623a89). However, it might be more useful to have a more concrete example of where the difference between super- and sub-type makes a difference that should be solvable by using `TREAT` as I'm struggling to work out where/how using `TREAT` in this way would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The st_geometry uses sdo_geometry as its storage. So you would assume the TREAT would happily return the st_geometry as no storage change is needed.

`select mdsys.st_point(1,2,26917).geom.get_wkt() as geom from dual;`

Conversion can be done directly,:

`select Mdsys.st_geometry(mdsys.st_point(1, 2, 26917).geom) as geom from dual`

Comment: Thanks Simon. I posted an answer that builds on yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72261312/5576771. Let me know if I misunderstood anything.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Simon's answer, here are the results from Simon's queries:

Query #1:

```
 select mdsys.st_point(1,2,26917).geom as geom from dual;
 --I removed .get_wkt().
 
 Result:
 [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]
```

Query #2:

```
 select Mdsys.st_geometry(mdsys.st_point(1, 2, 26917).geom) as geom from dual
 
 Result:
 [MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY]
```

So I think that means both queries worked. They converted the ST_POINT subtype to the ST_GEOMETRY supertype.

---

I used CTRL+F5 to run the queries in SQL Developer. If I'd used plain F5, I would have gotten different results, because F5/SQLPLUS automatically converts the result to a textual representation of the geometry. So the result for the queries would have been `POINT (1.0 2.0)`, which is misleading. The result is really `[MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY]`.

---

Related: [Unsupported datatype in Live SQL: st_geometry(st_point(1, 2, 26917).geom)](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4498525/unsupported-datatype-in-live-sql-st-geometry-st-point-1-2-26917-geom/)