# Testing a UDT in Oracle Live SQL: Describe a query's column datatype without creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes, user-defined-types, oracle18c

I'm testing a [user-defined datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133976/convert-udt-subtype-to-supertype#comment127453360_72133976) in the Oracle Live SQL online environment (normally I'd use db<>fiddle, but db<>fiddle doesn't know how to output UDT values...instead, it outputs an empty resultset, which isn't very helpful).

When I run a query that returns a UDT value, I want to verify ***what*** datatype is being returned. (The [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example below is simple/obvious, but my actual code is more complicated...it's not always clear what UDT supertype/subtype is being returned.)

Currently, Oracle Live SQL returns an `[unsupported data type]` value:

```
create or replace type "MY_ST_GEOMETRY" authid current_user as object (
    entity   integer,
    constructor function my_st_geometry (
        geom_str clob,
        srid number
    ) return self as result
        deterministic,
    constructor function my_st_geometry (
        srid   integer
    ) return self as result
        deterministic
) not final alter type "MY_ST_GEOMETRY" add constructor function my_st_geometry (
    center_x        number
) return self as result
    deterministic
cascade;
/

with data as (
select my_st_geometry('point(10 10)',26917) as shape from dual)
select shape from data
```

Result:

```
SHAPE
-----------------------
[unsupported data type]
```

---

Determining the datatype:

I'm aware that I can create a view from the query, and then look at `user_tab_columns` to see the datatype:

```
select data_type
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'MY_ST_GEOMETRY_VW';
```

Result:

```
DATA_TYPE
--------------
MY_ST_GEOMETRY
```

That works, but in the future, it would be nice if I could determine the datatype without needing to create a view.

---

Is there a way to describe a query's column datatype — without creating a view?

Oracle Live SQL *[here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/nnl8wzc854tqpjavkaewuhjpk)*

Comment: Side note: In other tests, if I'm trying to determine if a value's type is a subtype of some supertype, then I suppose I could use `IS OF` *type*: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/functions-and-operators-useful-with-objects.html#GUID-E04639B8-949A-4FF7-ADBF-FEFE8646FFF1

Comment: @astentx Yes, thanks. This is what I needed: `sys.anydata.gettypename(sys.anydata.convertobject(...))`.