# Convert MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING subtype value to MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY supertype

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, oracle18c, oracle-spatial

*This question pertains to Oracle 18c's [MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/sql-multimedia-type-support.html) datatype. Which is not to be confused with [Esri's SDE.ST_GEOMETRY](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm) datatype).*

---

The following query produces an MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING subtype value:

```
with data as (
select st_geometry.from_wkt('Linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)',26917) as shape from dual)

select
    shape
from
    data
    
Result:
[MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING]
```

In a query, I want to convert the MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING subtype value to the MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY supertype.

Reason: My GIS software can only handle MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY supertype values (not MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING subtype values). I don't have control over this limitation.

---

I tried using the TREAT() function to make the covnersion, but it didn't seem to have an effect. The result is still the MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING subtype:

```
with data as (
select st_geometry.from_wkt('Linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)',26917) as shape from dual)

select
    treat(shape as mdsys.st_geometry)
from
    data
  
The result is still:
[MDSYS.ST_LINESTRING]
```

---

How can I convert the MDSYS.ST_LINSTRING subtype value to the MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY supertype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SimonGreener pointed out that this works:

```
with data as (
select st_linestring.from_wkt('Linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)',26917) as shape from dual)

select
    treat(st_geometry(a.shape.geom) as mdsys.st_geometry) as shape
from
    data a


SHAPE
--------------
[MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY]
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to as a sub-type is always an instance of a super-type (and will have all the attributes and methods inherited from the super-type).

```sql
with data (shape) as (
  select st_geometry.from_wkt('Linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)',26917) from dual
)
select CASE WHEN shape IS OF(ST_GEOMETRY) THEN 'is' ELSE 'is not' END
         AS st_geometry,
       CASE WHEN shape IS OF(ST_CURVE) THEN 'is' ELSE 'is not' END
         AS st_curve,
       CASE WHEN shape IS OF(ST_LINESTRING) THEN 'is' ELSE 'is not' END
         AS st_linestring,
       CASE WHEN shape IS OF(ST_POLYGON) THEN 'is' ELSE 'is not' END
         AS st_polygon
from   data
```

Outputs:

> | ST_GEOMETRY | ST_CURVE | ST_LINESTRING | ST_POLYGON |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | is | is | is | is not |

So if you have a function that takes a super-type then just pass the sub-type to it and it will accept it.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION test_func(
  geom IN ST_GEOMETRY
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 42;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
with data (shape) as (
  select st_geometry.from_wkt('Linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)',26917) from dual
)
SELECT test_func(shape) FROM data;
```

or:

```sql
with data (shape) as (
  select TREAT(
           st_geometry.from_wkt('Linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)',26917)
           AS ST_LINESTRING
         )
  from   dual
)
SELECT test_func(shape) FROM data;
```

Both work as the function accepts the argument and output `42`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91570cbb72c1419a35a565b6f72ac58a)*